# Understanding Neural Network layers, nodes, and dot products

Tags: java, neural-network, deep-learning

I read through this page: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html to better understand how a neural network works. I want to create a simple feed forward network in Java that has no back propagation or training.

What I am fuzzy on is the math involved for each "Neuron" of a layer in a network. Say I have three layers. The first layer takes an input vector of size 100. Does this mean my first layer will have 100 Neurons? Does this also mean that the input for each Neuron will be the sum of all 100 inputs multiplied by weights? Is that sum the input to the activation function of my Neuron?

In the chapter it was mentioned that the sum of all inputs to a neuron/perceptron can be re-stated as the dot product of inputs (x) and weights (w). I can view them as two separate vectors and their dot product gives me x1w1 x2w2 x3w3 .. etc, but how does the sum of x1w1 + x2w2 + .. still equal the dot product?

Finally, if a layer is supposed to have an input of 100 and an output of 1000, does that mean that the layer will actually have 1000 neurons and each neuron takes 100 inputs? So the layer outputs 1 value per neuron, thus giving 1000 outputs?

I apologize in advance if these questions are completely off or trivial, I have read a few documents online and this is my understanding so far, but it is hard to verify without asking someone who really understands it. If you have additional resources or videos that will help, they are much appreciated.

Comment: Also, a good learning place is [deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org/neuralnet-overview) to understand the basics of neural nets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is my first answer in stackOverflow, so please, go easy.**

If i'm understanding your question right, you're wondering how the math behind an artificial neuron works. The neuron is made up of 5 components shown in the following list.
(The subscript i indicates the i-th input or weight.)

1. A set of inputs, xi.
2. A set of weights, wi.
3. A threshold, u.
4. An activation function, f.
5. A single neuron output, y.

The artificial neuron has a fairly simple structure.

Using the unit step activation function, you can determine a set of weights (and threshold value) that will produce the following classification:
[Click to view classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2apd.png)

Looking at number 4. An activation function f. Many different functions can take place with the identity function being the simplest.

The neuron output Y, is the result of applying the **activation function** to the **weighted sum** of the **inputs**, less the **threshold**.

This value can be discrete or real depending on the activation function used.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hHb5.png) an output of Y that holds a specific function F.

Once the output has been calculated, it can be passed to another neuron (or group of neurons) or sampled by the external environment.   The interpretation of the neuron output depends upon the problem under consideration

@Seephore

In principle, there is no limit on the number of hidden layers that can be used in an artificial neural network. Such networks can be trained using "stacking" or other techniques from the deep learning literature. Yes, you could have 1000 layers, though I don't know if you'd get much benefit: in deep learning I've more typically seen somewhere between 1-20 hidden layers, rather than 1000 hidden layers. In practice the number of layers is based upon pragmatic concerns, e.g., what will lead to good accuracy with reasonable training time and without overfitting.

**What you're asking:**
  Im going to assume you meant to say 100 input and 1000 output?
When a input takes in the weighted value, its output gives it to all the other nodes (neurons) in the next layer, but the value is still from the given node.

There are many "wish wash" books out their for java, but if you really want to get into it read [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2apd.png)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. One more question for clarification: When a layer is defined as having 100 input and 1000 input, does that mean each neuron takes 100 inputs as a weighted sum and outputs 1 value and the layer has 1000 of these neurons?

Comment: Yes I meant 1000 output. You can reply via comment here instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: got it, like I said I'm new to this

Comment: So if a layer is defined as having 100 in and 1000 out, what that really means is that this one layer will have 1000 neurons. Each neuron will take in a input sum of 100 values multiplied by a weight and output 1 value for the next layer. So the next layer will need to have an input equal to the output of the previous layer. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The inputs need the output of the previous layer multiplied by a weight, if the output of one neuron has 100 in and 1000 out, the next layer has 1000 neurons.